# Prevent automatic update of modelMatrix and modify culling planes in rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to use par3d() to set a custom userMatrix in rgl, but due to the re-calculations of the read-only modelMatrix, unwanted side effects happen to the resulting view. (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.97.0/topics/par3d , Section:Rendering)
Additionally, the near and far culling planes (that I cannot seem to modify either) cut the objects too early when moved closer to/farther away from the viewpoint.

My goal is to interactively navigate (with the Z-axis is up) a point cloud with regression planes and surfaces more freely than otherwise possible with spin and zoom centered on the scene (I have seen the panning example using rgl.setMouseCallbacks).

Re-drawing the scene all over to move it is not really an option, but applying a custom transformation to some of the scene objects could be another approach, but more like a work-around.

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: You posted this to the rgl forum, and got an answer there.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My post did not get validated by admin throughout the day, and I noticed that there is not a lot of activity there. Different timezone I guess, and insufficient patience :/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague.  What are the "unwanted side effects"?  But I'll try:

In the simplest case, the model matrix M is set as U V, where V is set by the system (as described in ?par3d), and U is completely under your control.  So if you want complete control of M, first set U to the identity and read M to get V, and then to achieve a new M', set U to M' V^-1.

Clipping planes are a feature of the projection matrix.  You don't have a lot of control there.

Comment: The operations stated in the link have the effect that the scene is translated to zero and perspective recalculated according to zoom.
I did try to "trick" it but it is of no use as the model transformation is re-calculated immediately.
As far as I remember near and far planes are definitely a setting in OpenGL, probably not exposed by rgl.

Thanks for the input, though. If I could just disable updating of the model matrix it would be fine.

Comment: You keep making this claim on no basis whatsoever.  Disabling the model matrix updates would not fix the problem you are seeing.  If you disagree, try it:  `rgl` is open source, you can change anything you like.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is no basis for my claim, but maybe it is not clear from the information stated. It's been difficult to find the time, nevertheless I managed to get some first / 3rd person like view going with some debug print and won't investigate further.
It includes a modification to counter the effect of the model view transformation that seems to place the final resulting view well behind the object/scene to ensure it fits nicely in the viewport regardless of zoom and fov etc. - think this corresponds a bit to what I can interpret from the docs anyway. Sample code has to go below.

Answer (score 0):

So, this sample code produces a FPV or 3rd person view in rgl including a hack (fine tune the -550 constant) to get the view closer to the pivot point (which shouldn't be necessary if one would have full control over all matrices).
The near far clipping/culling is still there, but acceptable.

```
library("rgl")
library("Morpho")

rglInit <- function()
{
  rgl.open()
  rgl.viewpoint(fov=110, type="userviewpoint")

  defaultUserMatrix <<- par3d()$userMatrix
}

lookAt3d <-function(eye, center, up)
{
  cat("*** lookat\n")
  cat("eye\n")
  print(eye)
  cat("center\n")
  print(center)
  cat("up\n")
  print(up)

  fwd = center - eye
  fwd = fwd / sqrt(sum(fwd^2))
  upn = up / sqrt(sum(up^2))

  side = crossProduct(fwd, up)
  upnt = crossProduct(side, fwd)

  M = rbind(c(side, 0), c(upnt, 0), c(-fwd, 0), c(0,0,0,1))
  M = M %*% t(translationMatrix(-550 * fwd[1] - eye[1],
                                -550 * fwd[2] - eye[2],
                                -550 * fwd[3] - eye[3])) # -550 hack seems to put the view closer to the pivot point
  cat("result\n")
  print(M)
  return (M)
}

yawPitchDirection3d <- function(yawAngle, pitchAngle)
{
  c(
    cos(pitchAngle) * cos(yawAngle),
    cos(pitchAngle) * sin(yawAngle),
    sin(pitchAngle))
}

lookAtYawPitch3d <- function(eye, yawAngle, pitchAngle)
{
  fwd = yawPitchDirection3d(yawAngle, pitchAngle)
  lookAt3d(eye, eye + fwd, c(0,0,1))
}

addTestScene <- function()
{
  data(volcano)

  z <- 2 * volcano # Exaggerate the relief

  x <- 10 * (1:nrow(z)) # 10 meter spacing (S to N)
  y <- 10 * (1:ncol(z)) # 10 meter spacing (E to W)

  zlim <- range(z)
  zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1

  colorlut <- terrain.colors(zlen) # height color lookup table

  col <- colorlut[ z-zlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point

  rgl.surface(x, y, z, coords = c(1,3,2), color=col, back="lines")

  axis3d('x', pos=c( NA, 0, 0 ), col = "red")
  axis3d('y', pos=c( 0, NA, 0 ), col = "green")
  axis3d('z', pos=c( 0, 0, NA ), col = "blue")
}

view = list()

resetView <- function()
{
  view$yaw <<- 0.6
  view$pitch <<- -1
  view$eye <<- c(-360, -250,115)

  setView()
}

setView <- function(yawDiff = 0.0, pitchDiff = 0.0, fwdDiff = 0.0, sideDiff = 0.0,
                    newView = NULL, delta = T)
{
  view$yaw <<- view$yaw + yawDiff
  view$pitch <<- view$pitch + pitchDiff

  if (view$pitch > 0.99 * pi / 2)
  {
    view$pitch <<- 0.99 * pi / 2
  }
  if (view$pitch < -0.99 * pi / 2)
  {
    view$pitch <<- -0.99 * pi / 2
  }

  cat("*** Setview\n")
  cat("Yaw\n")
  print(view$yaw)
  cat("Pitch\n")
  print(view$pitch)
  cat("Eye\n")
  print(view$eye)

  fwd = yawPitchDirection3d(view$yaw, view$pitch)
  up = c(0,0,1)
  upn = up / sqrt(sum(up^2))

  side = crossProduct(fwd, up)

  view$eye <<- view$eye + sideDiff * side + fwdDiff * fwd

  userView = lookAtYawPitch3d(eye = view$eye,
                              yawAngle = view$yaw,
                              pitchAngle = view$pitch)

  par3d(userMatrix = userView)
}

setMouseCallbacks <- function()
{
  clickPrev <- list()

  rgl.setMouseCallbacks(1,
                        begin = function(x, y)
                        {
                          clickPrev$x1 <<- x
                          clickPrev$y1 <<- y
                        }, 
                        update = function(x, y)
                        {
                          setView(yawDiff = -0.05 * (x - clickPrev$x1) / pi,
                                  pitchDiff = -0.05 * (y - clickPrev$y1) / pi)

                          clickPrev$x1 <<- x
                          clickPrev$y1 <<- y

                          cat("*** Drag MB1\n")
                          cat("userMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$userMatrix)
                          cat("modelMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$modelMatrix)
                          cat("projMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$projMatrix)
                        }
  )

  rgl.setMouseCallbacks(2,
                        begin = function(x, y)
                        {
                          clickPrev$x2 <<- x
                          clickPrev$y2 <<- y
                        }, 
                        update = function(x, y)
                        {
                          setView(fwdDiff = -0.5 * (y - clickPrev$y2),
                                  sideDiff = -0.5 * (x - clickPrev$x2))

                          clickPrev$x2 <<- x
                          clickPrev$y2 <<- y

                          cat("*** Drag MB2\n")
                          cat("userMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$userMatrix)
                          cat("modelMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$modelMatrix)
                          cat("projMatrix\n")
                          print(par3d()$projMatrix)
                        }
  )
}

rglInit()
resetView()
addTestScene()
setMouseCallbacks()
```